# sharing image using FBGraph API is not working

Tags: iphone, facebook, fb-graph

I have used the below code to share an image on fb wall:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.selectedImage, 10);
NSMutableDictionary* variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"your caption message", @"message", imageData, @"data", nil];
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [[sharedSingleton fbGraph] doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
```

but the app is getting crashed when ever I try to share.
Guide me to solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

Try This Code.....

-(IBAction)postPictureButtonPressed:(id)sender {

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

//create a UIImage (you could use the picture album or camera too)
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 240, 240)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app1.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];


UIImage *tempimag=imgView.image;

//UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"75x75.png"];

//create a FbGraphFile object insance and set the picture we wish to publish on it
FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:tempimag];

NSLog(@"img posted");


//finally, set the FbGraphFileobject onto our variables dictionary....
[variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

[variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postPictureButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];

//the fbGraph object is smart enough to recognize the binary image data inside the FbGraphFile
//object and treat that is such.....
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postPictureButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);


NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile & photo albums...");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

// JSON EXAMPLE

.H FILE

NSMutableArray *arrRespone;

```
NSMutableDictionary *resultsDictionary;
```

.M FILE

## define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1

## define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.indiaglitz.com/json/vod_menu_init.asp"]

// [how can print array json values into uitableview in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418747/how-can-print-array-json-values-into-uitableview-in-iphone)

## import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableView1;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

arrRespone=[NSMutableArray new];

```
practice_ArrayForDisplayingEx=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"bhupi",@"bhupi",@"bhupi",@"bhupi",nil];


dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^
```

{

NSData* dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:dataURL waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

```
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
  {

  NSError *error;

  resultsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                        error:&error];

  NSDictionary  *arrDetails=[[resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"menu"] objectAtIndex:0] ;
  NSDictionary *genr=[[arrDetails valueForKey:@"categories"] objectAtIndex:0];

  NSLog(@"array detailsarray ====>%@",arrDetails);
  NSLog( @"genreee arrray==%@",genr);
  //NSLog(@"genrvalueeee -----%@",[genr valueForKey:@"genre"]);

  NSLog(@"counttttt===%d",[[genr valueForKey:@"genre" ] count]);
  NSLog(@"genre objectatindex==%@",[genr valueForKey:@"cliptype"]);

  for (int i=0;i<[[genr valueForKey:@"genre" ] count];i++)
  {

  ```
  NSDictionary *strDetails=[[genr valueForKey:@"genre"] objectAtIndex:i];
  NSString *str=[strDetails valueForKey:@"gname"];
  NSLog(@"First string details===>%@",str);


  [arrRespone addObject:str];

  NSLog(@"response ====>%@",arrRespone);
  ```

  }
  [tableView1 reloadData];
  }

## pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

  NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView");

  return 1;
  }
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return 45;

  NSLog(@"heightForRowAtIndexPath");

}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");

return  [arrRespone count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSLog(@"inside tableview");
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

  //TableCell *cell = (TableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {

  ```
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  ```

  }
  // cell.textLabel.text=[arrRespone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSLog(@"cellvalue:%@",cell.textLabel.text);
  NSLog(@"inside numberofRowsInsection");
  // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrRespone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

@end