# how can print array json values into uitableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, json

*JSON* format code looks like this:

```
{   
 "rates": {  
           "amc": "201",  
           "hyd": "500.50",  
           "guj": "200.10",  
           "afgd": "400"  
         } 
}
```

After parsing *JSON* values the above code array returns:

`array = [values valueForKey:@"rates"];`

which array return

```
{  
           amc = "201"; 
           hyd = "500.50";  
           guj = "200.10";  
           afgd = "400";
           ...........etc



}
```

But i want to print in `UITableView` look amc:201

How can i do this?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  [connection release];

   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   self.responseData = nil;

   values = [responseString JSONValue];
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *arrTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *arrValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   array =[values valueForKey:@"rates"];

   NSLog(@"array values:--> %@",array);
 //    NSLog(@"values:--> %@",values);
 //    NSLog(@"Particular values:--> %@",[[values valueForKey:@"rates"] valueForKey:@"AED"]);

   tempDict1 = (NSMutableDictionary *)array;            
   NSArray *arr;// =[[NSArray alloc]init];
   arr = [[tempDict1 valueForKey:@"rates"] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
   NSLog(@"arr-->%@",arr);
   NSString *subStar = @"=";
   [arrTitle removeAllObjects];
   [arrValues removeAllObjects];

   for (int i=0; i<[arr count]-1; i++)
   {
        [arrTitle addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:NSMaxRange([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:subStar])-1]];
        [arrValues addObject:[[arr objectAtIndex:i] substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange([[arr objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:subStar])]];
         NSLog(@"arrTitle is:--> %@",arrTitle);
   }

   tempDict1 = (NSMutableDictionary*)[array objectAtIndex:0];
   array = [values valueForKey:@"rates"];
   NSLog(@"tempDict--%@",[tempDict1 objectForKey:@"AED"]);

   [array retain];
   [tbl_withData reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What is `dz`? How is it declared?

Comment: did you even try googling? Look for a json parser or do it yourself. Hint: it's an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: ya already done dz one but problem is how use forloop to fetching values from nsdictionary to nsarray to print uitableview?????

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
NSMutableArray * array2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
[array addObject: [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"amc"]];    
[array addObject: [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"hyd"]];    
[array addObject: [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"guj"]];    
[array addObject: [[array objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"afgd"]];
```

now put array2 values in your table cell.

like:

```
cell.text=[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: thanq for valuable solution ...but dictionary contains 250 values ...so  how can put for loop condition in standoff dzz???

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
 NSDictionary *dict =[values valueForKey:@"rates"];
 NSString *str=[dict valueForKey:@"amc"];

You need to do this:-
 NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   self.responseData = nil;

   values = [responseString JSONValue];
   NSMutableArray *arrTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSMutableArray *arrValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSDictionary *dict =[values valueForKey:@"rates"];
 NSString *str=[dict valueForKey:@"amc"];
```

rest you can do according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Return type for **[values valueForKey:@"rates"] is a dictionary not array** of values.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [values valueForKey:@"rates"];
```

Now you can refer get **values** within dictionary using **objectForKey**

Or else if you want to store in array.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in [dict allKeys])
{
    array = [dict objectForKey:key];
}
```

So finally array has all the values within dictionary.

```
// returns no of rows
-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section  
{
    return [array count];
}

// contents of row will be    
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath     
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"test";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) 
     {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
     }

     // Configure the cell...
     NSString *value = [self. array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     cell.textLabel.text = value;

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: but the above code return only one values ...but my dictionary contains 200 values ...how can print all the values please help me ?>???

Comment: i can answer your above question if i can see the structure of received value.. Can you share it.

Comment: yes you can see the structure of receiving values is  shown above of the code.

Comment: array = [dict objectForKey:key];
am printing array values is  5.693399  but i want output on uitableview like as amc = 5.693399

Comment: either you can use default tableview cell / custom made